# wp_list_pages not showing cpt as I expected

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I have a CPT called 'vacancies' here is the code that registers it:

```
function register_cpt_vacancy() {
    $args = array('labels' => $labels, 'hierarchical' => false, 'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions'), 'taxonomies' => array('departments'), 'public' => true, 'show_ui' => true, 'show_in_menu' => true, 'menu_position' => 5, 'show_in_nav_menus' => true, 'publicly_queryable' => true, 'exclude_from_search' => false, 'has_archive' => true, 'query_var' => true, 'can_export' => true, 'rewrite' => true, 'capability_type' => 'post');
    register_post_type('vacancy', $args);
}
```

In a template footer I'm trying to do this:

```
wp_list_pages('post_type=vacancy');
```

Which - [from reading the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) I thought would work.

Is there another way to do this besides creating my own query and menu styles? This list of vacancies is appearing as a menu between two other wp menus called with `wp_nav_menu` so I would like it to be in a list structure like they are.

Any help or suggestions for different approaches welcomed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the [wp_list_pages docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_members_of_a_custom_post_type), it states that:

> If a given custom post type is hierarchical in nature, then
>   **wp_list_pages()** can be used to list the member of that custom post
>   type.

Based on your code, the CPT that you are attempting to use with wp_list_pages() is *not* hierarchical.

Therefore, two solutions:

### 1. Change the Custom Post Type

Make your post type hierarchical (like pages) by setting `'hierarchical' => true` and `'capability_type' => 'page'`.

### 2. Use a Different Function

I recommend using something like:

```
$vacancy_menu = get_posts( 'post_type=vacancy' );

if( $vacancy_menu ) : ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $vacancy_menu as $menu_item ) : 
      setup_postdata( $menu_item );?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Go to <?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you'd like, this could easily be setup as a function to create your own "wp_list_posts()" or set to match the html of wp_nav_menu().

Also, be sure to check out [this example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/list-posts-highlight-current/) from CSS Tricks as well for a similar explanation with info on how to apply "current" classes to the links.

Comment: Brilliant mate, thanks for the explanation, and workarounds!

Comment: You need to add setup_postdata( $menu_item ) in the loop, otherwise you end up with all the same links to the page you're on.